# Use oEmbed in List Items

Tags: plugins, youtube, oembed

I'm aware that WordPress has [oEmbed functionality](http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds). But the content to be embedded has to be on it's own line like so:

```
Lorem Ipsum

http://www.youtube.com/link/to/content

More Lorem Ipsum
```

Unfortunately, my markup looks like this so oEmbed doesn't work and I have to use a plugin.

```
<ul>
    <li>http://www.youtube.com/link/to/content</li>
    <li>http://www.youtube.com/link/to/content</li>
</ul>
```

Is there anyway I can get oEmbed to work without this plugin? A line or two in functions.php would be better than this plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `[embed]` shortcode around your items.

```
<ul>
    <li>[embed]http://www.youtube.com/link/to/content[/embed]</li>
...
```

Comment: I so overkilled it, didn't I... :)

Comment: This works great because it's already built in (I can't believe I missed it!). The only criticism is that I have to teach users to type in the embed code with a specific width. Hmmm.

Answer (score 2):

There is bit of special filtering by `WP_Embed` class that turns standalone links into target for embedding:

```
/**
 * Passes any unlinked URLs that are on their own line to {@link WP_Embed::shortcode()} for potential embedding.
 *
 * @uses WP_Embed::autoembed_callback()
 *
 * @param string $content The content to be searched.
 * @return string Potentially modified $content.
 */
function autoembed( $content ) {
    return preg_replace_callback( '|^\s*(https?://[^\s"]+)\s*$|im', array( $this, 'autoembed_callback' ), $content );
}
```

If we take that logic and adjust regex for your use case:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'autoembed_list_items', 8 );

function autoembed_list_items( $content ) {

    global $wp_embed;

    return preg_replace_callback( '|<li>(https?://[^\s"]+)</li>|im', array( $wp_embed, 'autoembed_callback' ), $content );
}
```

Comment: This works very well thanks! Is there any way I can set width of these items (but not other oEmbed items)?

Comment: +1 for the nicest "shooting with cannons at mice" answer of this year.

Comment: @BFTrick might be possible, but will need to reverse-engineer much more of it and I already overkilled it in first place :)